# Stream closed Exception while adding for 2nd time

Tags: java, file, lucene, stream, buffer

I am trying to index documents using Lucene... However I am getting a StreamClosed exception..

I think it is related more to Java then Lucene....

Can someone please guide..
The **code snippet** is as follows:

```
 static void indexDocs(File file,boolean flag,Directory dir,IndexWriterConfig iwc)
  throws IOException {
  // do not try to index files that cannot be read

      FileInputStream fis = null;
 if (file.canRead()) {

    if (file.isDirectory()) 
    {

     String[] files = file.list();
     System.out.println("list "  + files.length);
      if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Invoked for  "  +  i  +  "and  "  +   files[i]);            
          indexDocs(new File(file, files[i]),flag,dir,iwc);
        }
      }
   } 
    else {

        boolean flags=true;

      try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);

     } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

       fnfe.printStackTrace();
     }
      try {
          Document doc = new Document();         

          LineNumberReader lnr=new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));

          Field pathField = new StringField("path", file.getPath(), Field.Store.YES);
          doc.add(pathField);


          String line=null;
          int i=0;      

          doc.add(new StringField("TT",file.getName(),Field.Store.YES)); 

          BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

           doc.add(new TextField("DD", br));

           System.out.println("Looping Again");

          while(flags)
          {                      
              IndexWriter iwcTemp1=new IndexWriter(dir,iwc);

          while( null != (line = lnr.readLine()) ){  

            i++;   

          StringField sf=new StringField("EEE",line.trim(),Field.Store.YES);
            doc.add(sf);

            if(i%10000==0)
            {      
                System.out.println("Breaking   " +  i);
                lnr.mark(i);
                break;
            }               
            sf=null;
          }        
          if(line==null)
          {
              System.out.println("FALSE "   );
              flags=false;
          }               

          System.out.println("FILE NAME IS FTP "  +   file.getName());


          if (iwcTemp1.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND) {

              try
              {               
                iwcTemp1.addDocument(doc);
                iwcTemp1.commit();                                      
                iwcTemp1.close();

              }catch(Throwable t)
              {
                  lnr.close();
                    br.close();
                    fis.close(); 
                  t.printStackTrace();
              }

          } else {
              try
              {

            System.out.println("updating " + file);
            iwcTemp1.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.getPath()), doc);
              }catch(Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }        
          System.out.println("END OF WHILE");
          lnr.reset();
          }//end of While 
      }catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally {
       fis.close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Exception I am getting is on the line where I am adding Document to Writer...
**Exception trace:**

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:114)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:270)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerImpl.zzRefill(StandardTokenizerImpl.java:923)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerImpl.getNextToken(StandardTokenizerImpl.java:1133)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer.incrementToken(StandardTokenizer.java:171)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardFilter.incrementToken(StandardFilter.java:49)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverterPerField.processFields(DocInverterPerField.java:102)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.processDocument(DocFieldProcessor.java:245)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:265)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:432)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1513)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1188)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1169)
        at com.rancore.MainClass2.indexDocs(MainClass2.java:236)
```

Can someone please guide...Where am I going wrong...Kindly guide...

Answer (score 0):

Your exception handling is incorrectly structured. It shouldn't be possible to continue with the read code if new FileInputStream() throws an exception.

Comment: Well I know that exception handling is not properly done because I have not yet done it... I am concerned about the stream closed exception...

Comment: So fix your code. At present if you get an exception on the open, you are continuing with the read, and getting the exception. If you fix your exception handling it won't happen. Proper exception handling isn't optional, or something you just lather on afterwards. It's an essential part of your program design. For one thing, it prevents self-inflicted bugs like this from ever happening in the first place.

Comment: It is possible that you don't close the writer. Why are you closing writer only on CREATE_OR_APPEND... IndexWriterConfig creation is out of the scope of the snippet. (btw it's very hard to read/understand your code...)